# Converting MySQL query to Model

Tags: database, magento2.2

I have been building a module for Magento 2.2 but am having trouble figuring out the query. I have created one in PHPMyAdmin so I know it works there, but doing it with Model  is escaping me.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT customer_name,
           customer_email,
           entity_id
    FROM `sales_order_grid`
    WHERE status = 'complete'
) revrem
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name, order_id
    FROM sales_order_item
    WHERE updated_at > '2017-11-28 00:00:01'
) revprod
ON revrem.entity_id = revprod.order_id
```